# How can I use a regex expression to  look for a particular URL?

Tags: java, regex

I connected to a site using URLConnection and the result I'm looking for is the url inside these parenthesis: `callback_request("https://secure.runescape.com/m=displaynames/s=bOVZmsrjbNQzntbDei*324JUo*3ozJ7hR*h1KNlxc6kPaBeKCBrdKIxD*edhi4qH/check_name.ws?displayname=" + escape(text), handleResult);`

The problem I'm having is the : `s=bOVZmsrjbNQzntbDei*324JUo*3ozJ7hR*h1KNlxc6kPaBeKCBrdKIxD*edhi4qH` is random each time--it's the session.

How can I use a regex expression to scan the page and look for `https://secure.runescape.com/m=displaynames/(random_session_id)/check_name.ws?displayname=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("https://secure\\.runescape\\.com/m=displaynames/.*/check_name\\.ws\\?displayname=\\?");
        System.out.println(p.matcher("https://secure.runescape.com/m=displaynames/s=bOVZmsrjbNQzntbDei*324JUo*3ozJ7hR*h1KNlxc6kPaBeKCBrdKIxD*edhi4qH/check_name.ws?displayname=?").find());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
"https://secure\.runescape\.com/m=displaynames/s=[a-zA-Z1-9*]+/check_name\.ws\?displayname="
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know displayname will be last you can

```
String displayName = url.split("displayname=")[1];
```